# Wants to directly shift to the previous active tab in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser-tabs

I have multiple tabs open in the chrome browser and I wants to shift to the previous active tab is there any shortcut for that or can I define any shortcut for that.

Scenario :

Working on multiple tabs more then 10 , I google some thing and now I am on that tab, I wants to go the facebook tab were I was last in. Its not the previous tab its in the middle of the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to skip to the next open tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to skip to the previous open tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>8</kbd> to access the tab in those positions
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to go to the last open tab

I'm suspicious you are referring to going back to the tab you were on, after clicking a link that opens in a new tab. If so, it usually spawns in the next tab along, so going to the previous tab should do so. Otherwise, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>  will close the current tab, which should do so also.

A full list of keyboard shortcuts can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en). I'm not sure a keyboard shortcut for exactly what you want to do exists.

Edit: I now understand how you mean, in that if you open a new tab, it will open as the last tab. I don't believe there is any shortcut (or any way to create a shortcut) to return you to the tab you were just on.

Comment: not the previous tab, its previous open tab..

Comment: @AsimRazaKhan You mean one you just closed? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: @AsimRazaKhan Amended my answer, although I'm still not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: edited again...

Comment: @AsimRazaKhan I understand now. I agree the keyboard shortcut would be useful, but unfortunately I don't believe there is one.